# How to store Max value of a column as a integer in a database table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have created a table (table name - tblSample) in SQL Server Management Studio. which contains the field id and name. What I want to do is select the maximum value of id which I can do with the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM tblSample;
```

Now what I want to store the max id as integer value in C#. How I can do that.

Comment: Question is incomplete. Where do you wanna store it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Here's a good place to start reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: where you want to store the max id in other table or in variable

Answer (score 1):

Base on your question:

```
private void GetData()
    {
        //1
        string connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial 
            Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";

        //2
        string sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM tblSample";

        SqlConnection sqlCnn;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;

        //3
        sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        int storeMaxId = 0;
        try
        {
            //4
            sqlCnn.Open();
            //5
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn);
            //6
            storeMaxId = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
            //7
            sqlCmd.Dispose();
            sqlCnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }
```

1: This is the connection string. The line is self explanatory, you have to put in your serve name, db name, etc.

2: This is the query you want to execute.

3: You take the connection string from 1 and use the SqlConnection class to create a connection to your data base.

4: Open the connection

5: Create the command using the SqlCommand class using values from 1 and 2 as parameter.

6: You use the ExecuteScalar method to execute the command and get the single value. Convert that into an int and store in a variable.

7:Dispose all the open connection(very important)